# Picasaweb and Google Feed API

Tags: google-feed-api

I need some help with the google feeds API. My ex-colleagues wrote some javascript using the EmbedPicasaGallery. You can find the .md [here](http://oss.oetiker.ch/jquery/oetiker@johan).

They use a long script. I can post it if needed but the point is the Picasaweb feed API.

```
    if (meta_opts.authkey){
            authkey = '&authkey=' + meta_opts.authkey;
        }

        if (meta_opts.albumid) {
           showAlbum($this,meta_opts,meta_opts.albumid)
        }
        else {
            $this.prepend($album_list);
            $.getJSON('http://picasaweb.google.com/data/feed/api/user/' 
                + user + '?kind=album&access=visible' + authkey 
                + '&alt=json-in-script&thumbsize=' + meta_opts.size + 'c&callback=?',
                renderAlbumList
           );
        }
    };
```

The code that is broken (in my understanding) is

```
 $.getJSON('http://picasaweb.google.com/data/feed/api/user/' 
                + user + '?kind=album&access=visible' + authkey 
                + '&alt=json-in-script&thumbsize=' + meta_opts.size + 'c&callback=?',
                renderAlbumList
           );
```

I know picasa is slowly dissapearing. When you login you get a different type of url now:

```
https://get.google.com/albumarchive/NUMBERS/album/NUMBERSANDLETTERS
```

Whereas 'in the old days' you got

```
user/NUMBERS/album/NUMBERS
```

If I use the way of linking in the script and enter the details from the new method I get following error:

[javascript error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CIkE1.png)

Wheres if I leave out /album/NUMBERSANDLETTERS like this:

```
https://picasaweb.google.com/data/feed/api/user/117827817825830816166/
```

I get a list of the albums of the user.

Anybody knows how I can integrate the new way to get the old result?

Thanks, 
Thomas

Answer (score -1):

I've broaden my search by including Google Photo. I found a solution [here](http://justifiedgrid.com/support/faq/can-it-load-photos-from-picasa-google-or-google-photos/).

> ```
> Locate the album you wish to show.
>     1 Find a user profile on Google+
>     2 Click "photos", such as: https://plus.google.com/+JustinLeeSG/photos
>     3 Choose an album, such as: https://plus.google.com/photos/112290004776472583114/albums/5995482558738492129
> ```

From here on I knew the next steps. So

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! A link to a potential solution is always welcome, but please [add context around the link](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline. Take into account that being _barely more than a link to an external site_ is a possible reason as to [Why and how are some answers deleted?](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).